# Не создается "Поставщик данных .NET Framework для MySQL" после установки mysql коннектора

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework, entity

Создал проект WPF, установил mysql connector (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), добавил ссылку на dll библиотеку этого коннектора (C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.20\Assemblies\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.dll) в ссылки проекта. Через NuGet ещё установил MySQLDataEntity and MySQLDataEntityFramework.

Создал БД mysql и пытаюсь подключиться к ней чтобы создать в проекте классы сущностей БД (Добавить класс - Данные - Модель ADO.NET.EDM). Далее должно создаваться соединение. Как пишет MS, после установки mysql connector должно появится "Поставщик данных .NET Framework для MySQL на странице Выбор источника данных" (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql...l-server-ver15), но ничего подобного не появляется. И я не могу подключиться к созданной мной БД.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, в чем тут проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо дополнительно установить MySQL for VS https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/